# CSS for print on A4 full size

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, printing, xhtml

I need print XHTML page with CSS on A4, but Firefox lets me print only 20.2 cm width of page, Chrome even less than 20 cm. Height of printed page is the same problem. It differs in any browser.

Comment: Did you set all margins to null?

Comment: How does Firefox let you print only 20.2 cm width? Where are you checking this?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here [@page Rule](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm)

You can define a separate stylesheet for printers and use metric or imperial units for sizes.